# How do I delete aws s3 bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudformation

I've mistakenly configured a bucket policy with a name of nonexisting bucket (via cloudformation). Now I can't delete the stack (S3::DeleteBucketPolicy failed), and can't find any way to delete the policy manually. How do I do that?

Comment: Casting about for an API / CLI solution, but I'm sure AWS support could take for of this for you in seconds if you're paying for Business Support (or silver-level or whatever it is they're calling it these days)

Comment: @Christopher, how to do it with cli?

Comment: Not that I can find. I'd agree with John Wheal's two options below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** - Create a bucket with the incorrect name and then try deleting the stack. I can't imagine there would be any problems as the bucket would exist.

**Option 2** - Contact their support. If you don't have paid support, ask this question in their forum. Otherwise open a support ticket.

Comment: Bucket can't be created with bad name - support forum worked though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite a lot apparently, the only option if you don't have paid support is to request deletion on [aws forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa) including the name of the thing you can't delete.